# ColdFusion 9 server keeps restarting itself

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion, jrun

We have ColdFusion 9 (32bit) running on a Windows 2008 R2 (64bit) server with IIS 7.5.

For a few months now, the ColdFusion server keeps restarting itself at different intervals. We've seen it restarting 10 times a day but it can be all good for a week.

- Windows event viewer logs:

The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service for the "coldfusion" server is restarting.

- There are no recovery options selected in the windows service
- The application, exception, server, etc. logs don't give a clue
- The coldfusion-out log logs:

jrun: Memory allocation failed (unable to allocate cache info).

- There is a file generated in the Windows/Temp folder at the time of the crash of exactly 345MB each time. The name of the file start with GM* followed by 6 random characters.
- ColdFusion, JRun and Windows are updated to the latest version. Tried different versions of JRun.

The only clue I've found ([a discussion thread at Old Nabble](http://old.nabble.com/Faulty-Contact-Sheets-p25523109.html)) related to the error message and the generated tmp file are related to a image library called GraphicsMagick, but nothing on our system uses this library as far as we know. It could be coincidence.

I've run out of options... Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could increase the amount of RAM allocated to the JRUN server.  Go into the ColdFusion Administrator/JRUN Admin and increase the maximum size allocated to the CF Server.  Someone is using the GraphicsMagick library on the server and may be trying to process too large of an image causing the JVM to run out of memory.  Or locate the source of the GraphicsMagick module on the server and maybe update it to a more current version (it could be a bug causing the large image size) or a bug in the ColdFusion causing too-large of an image to be created.  If its a bug, you're just gonna get XXXMB dumps (related to your max JRUN Memory Size) instead tho.  http://www.fusion-reactor.com/ might be able to help you.

Comment: To clarify, we are the only users of the server. We have tried to upgrade the amount of RAM, but the dumps where exactly the same as before. Didnt notice an increase or decrease in the amount of crashes. Couldn't find any reference to GraphicsMagick either. The only thing that might be happening is that some ColdFusion component is using GraphicsMagick or it isn't GraphickMagick at all. I will have a look at fusion reactor.

Comment: +1 for Fusion Reactor.  I have FR deployed on several servers and it's been very helpful in tracking down a variety of unusual problems.